# Recommendation by a Senior Developer after an internship

Tags: internship, recommendation-letter

Having an internship at a small mobile development company, is it appropriate to ask for a recommendation by the senior developer who helped you throughout the internship?

A recommendation (evaluation which would become recommendation) by the company owner will be given, but having zero professional experience, is it a good idea to populate my resume with two different recommendations based on a same working period?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is it appropriate to ask for a recommendation by the senior developer who helped you throughout the internship?

Absolutely. If (s)he was the person you worked with the closest, that may give him/her a different viewpoint than that of the company owner.

Note though that the owner may get the info for his/her own recommendation from the very same person. So the two recommendations might turn out to be very similar. However, once you have both, it is up to you to decide how to use them. If they look too much alike, you can skip the worse of them. If they are different and both are positive about you, use both.

Comment: @Patrick Just ask him/her (and the company owner). You can always ask, they can always say no.

Comment: Re the last paragraph: Note that not everyone will give you a copy of the recommendation they would write, for any of many reasons, most of them legitimate. So you may not have the opportunity to pick and choose, beyond judging how enthusiastic they seemed when you asked if they'd be willing to act as references.